# VSCode Launch Page in Local Web Server

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want VSCode to launch the HTML file I'm working on into my local testing webserver (using the ctrl-shift-b key).

I have a local web server on my Ubuntu machine running with this command: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

I have this script in my tasks.json:

```html
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "linux": {
        "command": "xdg-open"
    },
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "never",
    "args": ["${file}"]
}
```

When I hit ctrl-shift-b, I get my file opened in Chrome using this path: 
file:///home/me/myproject/myfolder/index.html

Instead, when I hit ctrl-shift-b, I want it to launch using this URL:
http://localhost:8000/myfolder/index.html

Is there any way to re-jig the tasks.json to make this happen?

I have seen some suggestions of using npm and gulp with VSCode, but I'm wondering if a simple solution like I described above can be done?

I haven't been able to find documentation for the syntax used in the tasks.json example I provided above (i.e. other options to specify instead of ${file} etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Go to Extension then Use the Live Server Extension. Install it from VS Code directly. You'll then have a link in the bottom of your editor to start and run the server automatically and also view your HTML immediately.
Please check :live-server-web-extension and Live Server apps.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908158/how-to-set-local-web-server-in-visual-studio-code/47924544: Note that as of today, it hasn't been updated in 2 years and has hundreds of issues in Github. I just removed it due to some Content Security Policy quirks, not sure if this is still good in 2021.