# How to set local web server in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I am new in VS code and working in typescript.Just I am trying to set local server path to open my HTML file.how to set that and when I was trying to set always I am getting error. I can not use this (NPM install) and (NPM start) command in terminal.If I use this command I am getting error.
 Any proxy issue? How to resolve this issue in VS code?

Folder structure:

```
TsDemo--folder name

.vscode
   ->launch.json
   ->tasks.json
out
    ->app.js
    ->app.js.map

app.ts
index.html 
tsconfig.json
```

i follwed this link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2016/01/24/visual-studio-code-and-local-web-server/
but not working.
If I use this command: D:\TsDemo>NPM install

```
        D:\TsDemo>npm install
        npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
        npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
        npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/lite-server failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.232.192.45:8080
        npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
        npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
        npm ERR! network
        npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
        npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-20T14_16_49_680Z-debug.log
```

If I use this command: D:\TsDemo>NPM start

```
        D:\TsDemo>npm start
        >TSDEMO@1.0.0 start D:\TsDemo
        > npm run lite

        npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"

        > TSDEMO@1.0.0 lite D:\TsDemo

        >lite-server --port 10001

        'lite-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! TSDEMO@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server --port 10001`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the TSDEMO@1.0.0 lite script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
        npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?


        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\411732\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-20T14_07_41_636Z-debug.log
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! TSDEMO@1.0.0 start: `npm run lite`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the TSDEMO@1.0.0 start script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
        npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-20T14_07_41_694Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just use the Live Server Extension. Install it from VS Code directly and you will be fine. You'll then have a link in the bottom of your editor to start and run the server automatically and also view your HTML immediately.

Also check: [live-server-web-extension](https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension)
and [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)

Comment: Apparently not if you're using the "Remote SSH" extension -- the default for many current developers. I want to set breakpoints in VSC, open a URL in the browser, and have execution pause IN VSC at the breakpoint.

LiveServer doesn't do that, at least not without unmentioned configuration.

Comment: This helps a lot!, Thanks!

Comment: Note that as of today, it hasn't been updated in 2 years and has hundreds of issues in Github. I just removed it due to some Content Security Policy quirks, not sure if this is still good in 2021.

Comment: @MichaelJess: The Content Securtiy Policies have surely to do with your settings. The Application is still a great and helpful option for an integrated Live Server for Studio Code. [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer&ssr=false#review-details](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer&ssr=false#review-details)

Comment: @k.vincent It was a combination of the old live server and an equally old project template, even though I must say no idea how a plain HTML page would trigger this behavior. Anyhow, my recommendation stands in that it is best to look for well-maintained tools, and this isn't one of those. An up-to-date template with CLI dev server did it for me.

Comment: @MichaelJess Care to post an answer?

Comment: @ZX9 You mean in addition to the comment above? I do not believe what I did is generally applicable. I am used to working with dev servers running from CLIs, and that is what is typically included in dev tools these days. In my case, the issue went away when I used Vue CLI as opposed to trying to host the Vue app via this VSCode plugin.

Comment: Live Server is great, but if you need HTTPS during your testing and development regime beware it's not always functional.

Comment: This is great. Reduced development time a lot. This auto refresh on file save. Can instantly see changes.

Comment: As Live Server is no longer maintained, you can give [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server) a try.