# Connecting HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding and am trying to build a very basic website with html, css and js.

When referring to code in the html file from js, I encounter an issue.

My HTML file contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
       <title>random stuff</title>
       <script src="Mgen.js"> </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p id="quote"> quote </p>
   </body>  
 </html>
```

`Mgen.js` in `src="Mgen.js"` is a hyperlink that links to the correct js file, which file is stored in the same folder as the HTML file.

In Mgen.js I have included the following code to test the connection between the files:

```
let quote = document.getElementById('quote')
console.log(quote)
```

This gives the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at <anonymous> (undefined:1:13)
    at Module._compile (undefined:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (undefined:1159:10)
    at Module.load (undefined:981:32)
    at Module._load (undefined:822:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (undefined:77:12)
    at <anonymous> (undefined:17:47)
```

I have installed node.js and enabled and disabled auto-attach. I have also tried checking the code through a browser, here too no elements of the js file show (I tried this with different js code that should be shown in a browser if functional).

Comment: @rioV8 — While it isn't as clear as it could be, the question is about using the debugging features of VS Code to debug some JavaScript (and the problem is that VS Code is trying to run that code in Node.js instead of a browser). Removing the [tag:visual-studio-code] tag is not a good choice here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908158/how-to-set-local-web-server-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like your JavaScript is running on node. In that case, your JavaScript would run on the server (and not in the client - your browser). Only when JavaScript runs in the browser, there is the document.

Try one thing: Shut down node and just open the plain HTML file in your browser.
That should work in that regard, that `document` should now be defined, but you might encounter another error: Your quote `p` will not be defined, because you load the JavaScript and execute it before you define the paragraph. In that case: Place the script tag before the closing body tag.

Comment: Hi Lennart,

Thanks a lot for this answer. Is there also a way to solve this while JavaScript is running on the server? I would like to create more complex documents whereby I can use the DeBug console.

Comment: @Jesse — The code needs to run in a browser. You can't use Node.js to run it. Use the debugger in the browser. Or [connect the VS Code debug console to your browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug). You can't use Node.js.

Comment: What @Quentin says is correct. You can use node to run a webserver for more complex projects with frameworks like React or Angular, but I think it is pretty solid to learn the plain things first and do it like Quentin suggested.

Comment: Even if you were doing something in the browser that needed a web server, you'd still be doing it in the browser and would need to debug the code *in the browser*.

Comment: Absolutely right. I just wanted to give a little perspective on when he might use node.

Answer (score -2):

The imported JavaScript file is loading before the HTML DOM is ready.
Hence document elements will not be found.
then you can use it as text/javascript in the script tag

Use an example here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let quote = document.getElementById('quote')
    console.log("quote---",quote)
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: There is **no** point that a `<script>` element can load in a webpage where the `document` object is not available.